# Find all files in a directory that are not directories themselves

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

I am looking for a way to list all the files in a directory excluding directories themselves, and the files in those sub-directories.

So if I have:

```
./test.log
./test2.log
./directory
./directory/file2
```

I want a command that returns: ./test.log ./test2.log and nothing else.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you want `test.log`, `test2.log`, and `file2` then:

```
find . -type f
```

If you do not want `file2` then:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Answer (score 22):

If you need symlinks, pipes, device files and other specific elements of file system to be listed too, you should use:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -not -type d
```

This will list everything except directories.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to list all types _except_ directories. I was doing something like `find / -group xxx | xargs ls -l`. This would `ls -l <dir>` and then `ls -l <file>` each file in the dir. But using `-not -type d` excluded dirs from the output. Note that `! -type d` also works (and claims to be POSIX compliant per the man page)

Answer (score 3):

using find is simple as:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

Answer (score 1):

### `find` only regular files

Use the `-type f` option with `find` to find *only* regular files. **OR, to be even more-inclusive, use `-not -type d` to find all file types *except* directories.**

When listing all files, I like to also sort them by piping to `sort -V`, like this:

```sh
# find only regular files
find . -type f | sort -V

# even more-inclusive: find all file types _except_ directories
find . -not -type d | sort -V
```

From `man find`:

> `-type c`
>
> File is of type `c`:
>
> - `b` - block (buffered) special
> - `c` - character (unbuffered) special
> - `d` - directory
> - `p` - named pipe (FIFO)
> - `f` - regular file
> - `l` - symbolic link; this is never true if the `-L` option or the `-follow` option is in effect, unless the symbolic link is broken.  If you want to search for symbolic links when `-L` is in effect, use `-xtype`.
> - `s` - socket
> - `D` - door (Solaris)
>
> To search for more than one type at once, you can supply the combined list of type letters separated by a comma `,` (GNU extension).

### How to store the output of `find` (a multi-line string list of files) into a bash array

To take this one step further, here is **how to store all filenames into a bash indexed array called `filenames_array`**, so that you can easily pass them to another command:

```sh
# obtain a multi-line string of all filenames
filenames="$(find . -type f | sort -V)"
# read the multi-line string into a bash array
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a filenames_array <<< "$filenames"

# Now, the the variable `filenames_array` is a bash array which contains the list 
# of all files! Each filename is a separate element in the array.
```

Now you can pass the entire array of filenames to another command, such as `echo` for example, by using `"${filenames_array[@]}"` to obtain all elements in the array at once, like this:

```sh
echo "${filenames_array[@]}"
```

OR, you can iterate over each element in the array like this:

```sh
echo "Files:"
for filename in "${filenames_array[@]}"; do
    echo "  $filename"
done
```

Sample output:

```
Files:
  ./file1.txt
  ./file2.txt
  ./file3.txt
```

### References:

1. I was reminded of `find . -type f` from [the main answer by @John Kugelman here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300665/4561887).
2. I borrowed the part to read the multi-line string into a bash array from my own answer here: [How to read a multi-line string into a regular bash "indexed" array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575442/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f
```

Comment: You are right, misread the question.  John Kugelman posted a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /some/directory -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find . -type f -print
```

Each file will be on its own line.  You must be in the directory you want to search.

Answer (score -1):

One more option

```
ls -ltr | grep ^-
```

to list all files, while

```
ls -ltr | grep ^d
```

to list all directories