# Convert line-endings for whole directory tree (Git)

Tags: git, line-endings

Following situation:

I'm working on a Mac running OS X and recently joined a project whose members so far all use Windows. One of my first tasks was to set up the codebase in a Git repository, so I pulled the directory tree from FTP and tried to check it into the Git repo I had prepared locally. When trying to do this, all I got was this

```
fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in blog/license.txt.
```

Since this affects all files below the "blog" folder, I'm looking for a way to conveniently convert ALL files in the tree to Unix line-endings. Is there a tool that does that out of the box or do I get scripting something myself?

For reference, my Git config concerning line-endings:

```
core.safecrlf=true
core.autocrlf=input
```

Answer (score 377, accepted):

[dos2unix](https://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html) does that for you.  Fairly straight forward process.

```
dos2unix filename
```

Thanks to toolbear, here is a one-liner that recursively replaces line endings and properly handles whitespace, quotes, and shell meta chars.

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

If you're using dos2unix 6.0 binary files will be ignored.

Comment: `find blog -type f | xargs dos2unix` should be faster.  You don't need the `-name *.*` either, unless you specifically want only files with a period somewhere in the name.  That's a windows glob, not a *nix one.

Comment: Piping `find` to `xargs` will fail if `find` matches any files with whitespace, quotes, or other shell meta characters in their path. At the least use `find blog -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix` to handle the case of whitespace. You have to use `find`'s `-exec` instead of piping to avoid quotes, etc.. The `dos2unix` man page doesn't specify what its behavior is if you invoke it on binary files. If it converts CRLF in binary files, it will corrupt them. See my answer for a safer, albeit longer alternative.

Comment: @lukmdo which is not the version installed on centos 6.4..... which does clobber them.... instead I had to d/l from here http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=dos2unix

Comment: Addendum: The dos2unix CLI is most easily installed via Homebrew (and not npm).

Comment: How would one ignore directories using this approach, if possible?

Comment: I needed to use dumb quotes after all because my file names contained (at least) commas: `find . -type f -exec dos2unix "{}" \;`.

Comment: KDiff3 tells me that this command changed encoding for me from UTF-8-BOM to System (?), which wasn't great. Though it looks like [the default encoding for dos2unix is `ascii`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/dos2unix.htm), which is should be UTF-8? Any idea what happened there?

Comment: Worth noting to not run this tool directly in your repo, otherwise it will destroy your `.git` and you will have to clone from origin :)

Comment: @DenisDrescher Could please explain what does  {} and \ mean ?

Comment: @kajibu The man page can explain it better: “The expression must be terminated by a semicolon (`;`).  If you invoke find from a shell you may need to quote the semicolon if the shell would otherwise treat it as a control operator.  If the string `{}` appears anywhere in the utility name or the arguments it is replaced by the pathname of the current file.”

Comment: Windows / PowerShell users, see this script which also uses dos2unix - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676361/how-to-run-dos2unix-for-all-files-in-a-directory-and-subdirecty-in-powershell

Comment: I had to do the opposite change, unix2dos also exist and works the same

Comment: You can use the one-liner `git grep --cached -Ilz '' | xargs -0 dos2unix` to change all git managed text files and will not include anything else if you're in a git project.

Comment: Why using additional commands like find, perl or xargs if you can use just dos2unix?
Like this: dos2unix *

Comment: You could also simply use `find blog -type f -exec dos2unix {} +` which will place as much files as possible instead of the placeholder, but could result in multiple invocations based on how many matches are found. For "few" files this results in a single invocation, too (like `xargs`). It's specific to GNU `find`, however.

Answer (score 63):

Assuming you have GNU `grep` and `perl` this will recursively convert CRLF to LF in non-binary files under the current directory:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -qIP '\r\n' {} ';' -exec perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' {} '+'
```

#### How it Works

Find recursively under current directory; change `.` to `blog` or `whatev` subdirectories to limit the replacement:

```
find .
```

Only match regular files:

```
  -type f
```

Test if file contains CRLF. Exclude binary files. Runs `grep` command for every regular file. That's the price of excluding binaries. If you have an old `grep` you could try building a test using the `file` command:

```
  -exec grep -qIP '\r\n' {} ';'
```

Replace CRLF with LF. The `'+'` with the second `-exec` tells `find` to accumulate matching files and pass them to one (or as few as possible) invocations of the command -- like piping to `xargs`, but without problems if file path contains spaces, quotes, or other shell meta characters. The `i` in `-pi` tells perl to modify the file in place. You could use `sed` or `awk` here with some work, and you'll probably change '+' to ';' and invoke a separate process for each match:

```
  -exec perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' {} '+'
```

Comment: In case it helps anyone: `grep -qIP '\r\n'` never matches anything on my CentOS system.  Changing it to `grep -qIP '\r$'` worked.

Comment: Hate to ask in comments, but is there a way to exclude a folder like `node_modules`?

Comment: @datatype_void take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command/15736463#15736463 for how to modify the `find` portion of the command to exclude directories. They suggest using `-path`, but you can also use `-regex` or `-iregex`, i.e. `-not -regex '.*/node_modules/.*'` which will exclude a `node_modules` at any depth.

Comment: Sorry if I come off as a `regex` or `bash` noob, but what about multiple exclusions, say `node_module` and `dist` for example?

Comment: GNU grep is required for the `-P` flag. OS X switched from GNU grep to BSD grep. Some alternatives for OS X: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches

Comment: I also needed to use "\r$" on Linux Mint as @SteveOnorato suggested. Weird

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of how it works. That helps us understand and learn better than just copying and pasting!

Comment: So, in linux mint the command becomes `find . -type f -exec grep -qIP '\r$' {} ';' -exec perl -pi -e 's/\r$/\n/g' {} '+'`

Answer (score 35):

Here's a better option: [Swiss File Knife](http://stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=remcrlf). It works recursively across sub-directories, and handles properly spaces and special characters.

All you have to do is:

```
sfk remcr -dir your_project_directory
```

---

Bonus: **sfk** also does lots of other conversions. See below for the full list:

```
SFK - The Swiss File Knife File Tree Processor.
Release 1.6.7 Base Revision 2 of May  3 2013.
StahlWorks Technologies, http://stahlworks.com/
Distributed for free under the BSD License, without any warranty.

type "sfk commandname" for help on any of the following.
some commands require to add "-help" for the help text.

   file system
      sfk list       - list directory tree contents.
                       list latest, oldest or biggest files.
                       list directory differences.
                       list zip jar tar gz bz2 contents.
      sfk filefind   - find files by filename
      sfk treesize   - show directory size statistics
      sfk copy       - copy directory trees additively
      sfk sync       - mirror tree content with deletion
      sfk partcopy   - copy part from a file into another one
      sfk mkdir      - create directory tree
      sfk delete     - delete files and folders
      sfk deltree    - delete whole directory tree
      sfk deblank    - remove blanks in filenames
      sfk space [-h] - tell total and free size of volume
      sfk filetime   - tell times of a file
      sfk touch      - change times of a file

   conversion
      sfk lf-to-crlf - convert from LF to CRLF line endings
      sfk crlf-to-lf - convert from CRLF to LF line endings
      sfk detab      - convert TAB characters to spaces
      sfk entab      - convert groups of spaces to TAB chars
      sfk scantab    - list files containing TAB characters
      sfk split      - split large files into smaller ones
      sfk join       - join small files into a large one
      sfk hexdump    - create hexdump from a binary file
      sfk hextobin   - convert hex data to binary
      sfk hex        - convert decimal number(s) to hex
      sfk dec        - convert hex number(s) to decimal
      sfk chars      - print chars for a list of codes
      sfk bin-to-src - convert binary to source code

   text processing
      sfk filter     - search, filter and replace text data
      sfk addhead    - insert string at start of text lines
      sfk addtail    - append string at end of text lines
      sfk patch      - change text files through a script
      sfk snapto     - join many text files into one file
      sfk joinlines  - join text lines split by email reformatting
      sfk inst       - instrument c++ sourcecode with tracing calls
      sfk replace    - replace words in binary and text files
      sfk hexfind    - find words in binary files, showing hexdump
      sfk run        - run command on all files of a folder
      sfk runloop    - run a command n times in a loop
      sfk printloop  - print some text many times
      sfk strings    - extract strings from a binary file
      sfk sort       - sort text lines produced by another command
      sfk count      - count text lines, filter identical lines
      sfk head       - print first lines of a file
      sfk tail       - print last lines of a file
      sfk linelen    - tell length of string(s)

   search and compare
      sfk find       - find words in binary files, showing text
      sfk md5gento   - create list of md5 checksums over files
      sfk md5check   - verify list of md5 checksums over files
      sfk md5        - calc md5 over a file, compare two files
      sfk pathfind   - search PATH for location of a command
      sfk reflist    - list fuzzy references between files
      sfk deplist    - list fuzzy dependencies between files
      sfk dupfind    - find duplicate files by content

   networking
      sfk httpserv   - run an instant HTTP server.
                       type "sfk httpserv -help" for help.
      sfk ftpserv    - run an instant FTP server
                       type "sfk ftpserv -help" for help.
      sfk ftp        - instant anonymous FTP client
      sfk wget       - download HTTP file from the web
      sfk webrequest - send HTTP request to a server
      sfk tcpdump    - print TCP conversation between programs
      sfk udpdump    - print incoming UDP requests
      sfk udpsend    - send UDP requests
      sfk ip         - tell own machine's IP address(es).
                       type "sfk ip -help" for help.
      sfk netlog     - send text outputs to network,
                       and/or file, and/or terminal

   scripting
      sfk script     - run many sfk commands in a script file
      sfk echo       - print (coloured) text to terminal
      sfk color      - change text color of terminal
      sfk alias      - create command from other commands
      sfk mkcd       - create command to reenter directory
      sfk sleep      - delay execution for milliseconds
      sfk pause      - wait for user input
      sfk label      - define starting point for a script
      sfk tee        - split command output in two streams
      sfk tofile     - save command output to a file
      sfk toterm     - flush command output to terminal
      sfk loop       - repeat execution of a command chain
      sfk cd         - change directory within a script
      sfk getcwd     - print the current working directory
      sfk require    - compare version text

   development
      sfk bin-to-src - convert binary data to source code
      sfk make-random-file - create file with random data
      sfk fuzz       - change file at random, for testing
      sfk sample     - print example code for programming
      sfk inst       - instrument c++ with tracing calls

   diverse
      sfk media      - cut video and binary files
      sfk view       - show results in a GUI tool
      sfk toclip     - copy command output to clipboard
      sfk fromclip   - read text from clipboard
      sfk list       - show directory tree contents
      sfk env        - search environment variables
      sfk version    - show version of a binary file
      sfk ascii      - list ISO 8859-1 ASCII characters
      sfk ascii -dos - list OEM codepage 850 characters
      sfk license    - print the SFK license text

   help by subject
      sfk help select   - how dirs and files are selected in sfk
      sfk help options  - general options reference
      sfk help patterns - wildcards and text patterns within sfk
      sfk help chain    - how to combine (chain) multiple commands
      sfk help shell    - how to optimize the windows command prompt
      sfk help unicode  - about unicode file reading support
      sfk help colors   - how to change result colors
      sfk help xe       - for infos on sfk extended edition.

   All tree walking commands support file selection this way:

   1. short format with ONE directory tree and MANY file name patterns:
      src1dir .cpp .hpp .xml bigbar !footmp
   2. short format with a list of explicite file names:
      letter1.txt revenues9.xls report3\turnover5.ppt
   3. long format with MANY dir trees and file masks PER dir tree:
      -dir src1 src2 !src\save -file foosys .cpp -dir bin5 -file .exe

   For detailed help on file selection, type "sfk help select".

   * and ? wildcards are supported within filenames. "foo" is interpreted
   as "*foo*", so you can leave out * completely to search a part of a name.
   For name start comparison, say "\foo" (finds foo.txt but not anyfoo.txt).

   When you supply a directory name, by default this means "take all files".

      sfk list mydir                lists ALL  files of mydir, no * needed.
      sfk list mydir .cpp .hpp      lists SOME files of mydir, by extension.
      sfk list mydir !.cfg          lists all  files of mydir  EXCEPT .cfg

   general options:
      -tracesel tells in detail which files and/or directories are included
                or excluded, and why (due to which user-supplied mask).
      -nosub    do not process files within subdirectories.
      -nocol    before any command switches off color output.
      -quiet    or -nohead shows less output on some commands.
      -hidden   includes hidden and system files and dirs.
      For detailed help on all options, type "sfk help options".

   beware of Shell Command Characters.
      command parameters containing characters < > | ! & must be sur-
      rounded by quotes "". type "sfk filter" for details and examples.

   type "sfk ask word1 word2 ..."   to search ALL help text for words.
   type "sfk dumphelp"              to print  ALL help text.
```

EDIT: a word of caution: be careful when running this on folders that have binary files, as it will effectively destroy your files, **particularly .git directories**. If this is your case, do **not** run sfk in the entire folder, but select specific file extensions instead (*.rb, *.py, etc). Example: `sfk remcr -dir chef -file .rb -file .json -file .erb -file .md`

Comment: Works great on OSX Mavericks. No need to install anything, just run the script from the mounted dmg and your terminal appears ready to go.

Comment: @Gui Ambros You don't need to worry about the files inside .git folder. sfk does not update files inside hidden folders by default.

Comment: @bittusarkar: At the time of my answer, `sfk` effectively processed my entire .git folder and destroyed a bunch of binaries (hence my *edit*; don't remember if it was Linux or Mac). They may have changed the default behavior in more recent versions, but I'd still recommend to specify the extension, to be safe.

Comment: This worked well for me, after having spent too much time trying to normalize my repos using recommended git commands that simply did not fix all the relevant files.

Comment: Thanks! Just used this to convert a whole bunch of files quickly and painlessly and now I can add them to the staging area in Git.  On OSX 10.9.5, and not sure where the files were created.

Answer (score 25):

```
find . -not \( -name .svn -prune -o -name .git -prune \) -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g' {} \;
```

This is much safer as it avoids corrupting your git repo. Add or replace .git, .svn with .bzr, .hg or whatever source control your using to the **not** list.

Comment: This is the best answer if you didnt have to install anything like dos2unix. Allows exclusion of file types and avoids corrupting source code files.

Answer (score 10):

On OS X, this worked for me:

```
find ./ -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g' {} \;
```

Warning: Please backup your directory before executing this command.

Comment: Just want to note that this corrupted my git repository. I tried again by moving out the .git folder before running and moving it back in afterwards with better success.

Comment: I'll also note that this doesn't exclude binary files, so it will e.g. corrupt your jpgs.

Comment: this needs a bigger warning, not really a great solution

Comment: This is a very, very naive solution.

Answer (score 10):

The current accepted answer uses `find -exec` with `dos2unix` but this is unnecessary nowadays because the vast majority of shells, including Bash, support the use of a wildcard to operate on all files in a directory (known as *pathname expansion* or *globbing*). The answers that don't use `dos2unix` are even worse because they do naive search-and-replaces that will irreversibly corrupt binary files like executables, images and videos, and even the contents of the `.git` directory.

Both `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` are ubiquitous, lightweight tools that have been pre-installed on every UNIX-based system I've ever used, meaning they're almost definitely already installed on your system. They also skip non-text files by default, making them safe to use on entire directories in this way unlike other answers.

#### To convert all line endings to UNIX line endings (LF)

```
dos2unix -v *
```

#### To convert all line endings to Windows line endings (CRLF)

```
unix2dos -v *
```

The `-v`/`--verbose` switch isn't required but will output which files are being converted to the console.

Answer (score 4):

Here a solution if using sed:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/\r$//' {} \;
```

`-i` stands for in-place, if you want to create a backup as well use `-i.bak`

`'s/\r$//'` will replace all carriage returns(`\r`) at end of each line

Comment: When you run it in a git repository, you will probably see `sed: cannot rename ./.git/objects/16/sed68Vezl: Permission denied`. You must exclude `.git` folder in that case.

Comment: Be careful not to run this command on binary files, like `.mp4`, `.jpg` or `.png`, because it will corrupt them.

Comment: Another naive and irresponsible solution, this shouldn't have upvotes until it's made clear what the risks of running it are.

Answer (score 0):

```
 find ./ -type f -name "*.java" -exec perl -pi -e 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g' {} \;
```

This has worked for me on wsl2 to change all the java files from CRLF to LF

Answer (score 0):

The same as the others but with node.js

```
find ./src/test/resources/com/sonalake/bss/tests/bdd/ -type f -exec node -e "require('fs'); const val = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[1], 'utf8'); fs.writeFileSync(process.argv[1], val.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n'))" {} ';'
```

```
// load file system module
require('fs');
// read file
const val = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[1], 'utf8');
// replace file contents
fs.writeFileSync(process.argv[1], val.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n'))
```