# Convert line-endlings for whole directory tree to \r\n

Tags: windows, line-endings

As the question [Convert line-endlings for whole directory tree (Git)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068179/convert-line-endlings-for-whole-directory-tree-git) but to Windows \r\n

Only text files (eg: .html, .css, .js, .php)

Assume complex scenarios, such as files with mixed line endings (Unix and Windows)

Comment: Have you searched or tried?  The linked article gives the clue - which  leads to 'tofrodos'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's `find`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm). [Here's `unix2dos`](http://www.bastet.com/). Same solution applies.