# How to run dos2unix for all files in a directory and subdirecty in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I can run `dos2unix` on one file in PowerShell:

```
dos2unix ./assets/style.css
```

How to do this for all CSS files under `./assets/` and its subdirectories?

Answer (score 7):

```powershell
'.\assets' | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.css' | ForEach-Object {
    dos2unix $_.FullName
}
```

#### Explanation

`Get-ChildItem` is like `dir` or `ls` (in powershell the latter 2 are aliases for that cmdlet).
`-File` means return only files.
`-Recurse` means recurse child directories.
`-Filter` allows us to get only the file pattern desired.

Then we pipe that into `ForEach-Object` to execute a script block *for each file returned* and in there, we just execute the dos2unix command.

`FullName` is the property of the file object that contains the full path to the file.

Comment: Curious use of piping WRT `'.\assets'`.  Why not just `Get-ChildItem Assets -Recure -Filter *.css | Foreach {dos2unix $_.FullName}`?  Note that you don't need to quote `*.css`.  Also, use of -File will only work on PowerShell v3 and later.

Comment: I prefer that style. So I tend to do things like `$path | Join-Path -Child Path 'whatever'` when possible. I just like the pipeline! Good point about `-File`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to run it quietly, so it doesn't print output?

Comment: Try piping it to `Out-Null`. I'm on mobile now so I can't post a proper example.