# How to run dos2unix for all the files in subfolders in bash?

Tags: bash, dos2unix

I am using `dos2unix *.sh` to convert all the `.sh` files in the current directory.

So how to convert all the `.sh` files in the subfolders as well?

I tried this but it does not work for bash:
[How to run dos2unix for all files in a directory and subdirecty in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676361/how-to-run-dos2unix-for-all-files-in-a-directory-and-subdirecty-in-powershell)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.sh" -exec dos2unix {} \+;
```

this locates all `*.sh` (`-name "*.sh"`) files (`-type f`) in the current directory (recursing into subdirectories as well) and executes on all of them the `dos2unix` utility

Comment: thank you, it works! now I want to do `qsub *.sh` for all the files as well. I tried `find . -type f -name "*.sh" -exec qsub {} \+;`, but why only one job was submitted?