# Convert line endings in all non-binary files under a directory

Tags: linux, line-endings

Is it feasible to fix line endings in all non-binary files under a directory?
There are a lot of answers how to fix line endings in a file.
I'm wondering if it is possible for the command to analyze all files and fix only those which needed.

Comment: find ./ -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;

[source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068179/convert-line-endlings-for-whole-directory-tree-git)

Answer (score 0):

`find ./ -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068179/convert-line-endlings-for-whole-directory-tree-git) – Mykhaylo Adamovych

Comment: Note that there are different implementations of dos2unix. Not all of them automatically skip binary files. First check if your dos2unix version skips binary files.