# How to only find files in a given directory, and ignore subdirectories using bash

Tags: bash, unix

I'm running the `find` command to find certain files, but some files in sub-directories have the same name which I want to ignore.

I'm interested in files/patterns like this:

```
/dev/abc-scanner, /dev/abc-cash ....
```

The command:

```
find /dev/ -name 'abc-*'
```

What's being returned:

```
/dev/abc-scanner
/dev/abc-cash
...
...
...
/dev/.udev/names/abc-scanner
/dev/.udev/names/abc-cash
```

I want to ignore the latter files: `/dev/.udev/...`

Comment: ignore specific subdirectories, or not descend into any subdirectories? For the latter, use the -maxdepth 1 option

Comment: @frankc Post it as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [exclude directory from find . command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command)

Answer (score 305, accepted):

If you just want to limit the find to the first level you can do:

```
 find /dev -maxdepth 1 -name 'abc-*'
```

... or if you particularly want to exclude the `.udev` directory, you can do:

```
 find /dev -name '.udev' -prune -o -name 'abc-*' -print
```

Note that `/dev` is the directory from the question; you will want to replace that with the directory you wish to search.

Comment: If I wanted to list where all the above symlinks pointed to found in the above pattern, would I just use a pipe? Something like find /dev -maxdepth 1 -name 'abc-*' | ls -l

Comment: It's better to use `xargs` instead, so something like: `find /dev -maxdepth 1 -name 'abc-*' | xargs ls -l` but if there's any chance that they will have whitespace in the names, you should do `find /dev -maxdepth 1 -name 'abc-*' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l`

Comment: However, as [Stephen Darlington's answer points out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715485/how-to-only-find-files-in-a-given-directory-and-ignore-subdirectories-using-bash/7715550#7715550), I'm not sure why you wouldn't just do `ls -l /dev/abc-*`

Comment: Also, if you want to find out where symlinks point to, you can do `for x in /dev/abc-*; do readlink -f $x; done`

Comment: Or if you want subdirectories only on the first level, `ls -l /dev/abc-* /dev/*/abc-* | fgrep -v /dev/.udev` ... except at least on my Linux `/dev/*/*` does not include files in `/dev/.udev/*` so you can omit the `fgrep -v`.

Comment: The `-maxdepth` argument is a "global" option, so you must specify it before the other options (as shown above) or you'll get a warning message.

Answer (score 13):

Is there any particular reason that you need to use `find`? You can just use `ls` to find files that match a pattern in a directory.

```
ls /dev/abc-*
```

If you do need to use `find`, you can use the `-maxdepth 1` switch to only apply to the specified directory.

Comment: I think you mean `-maxdepth 1` rather than `-maxdepth 0`

Comment: It should be pointed out that the wildcard is the important part here, not `ls`.  You can find the same files with `echo` or `wc` or what have you, because the shell expands the wildcard for you.  So `for file in /dev/abc-*; do something with each "$file"; done` might be what the OP is actually looking for.

Comment: Ah, I can never remember which way round it is... Thanks for the edit. Also, worth noting that it's not universal. The Solaris version of `find` doesn't have it for example.

Comment: @tripleee +1. Yup. Doing it all in the shell would be preferable if possible.

Comment: Also if there are subdirectories named `abc-*` you will get the wrong result from `ls -l`, but perhaps `ls -ld` is acceptable as a workaround.

Comment: If you need to process the files returned by ls, you can use a for loop. For example: `for f in \`ls /dev/abc-*\`; do echo $f; done`

Comment: @MustafaOzturk As tripleee notes, you don't need the ls in back ticks. The shell expands the wildcard, so the ls is superfluous.

Comment: @StephenDarlington backticks are needed for the for loop example that I gave. Without it bash treats ls as a item in a list. `for f in ls; do echo $f; done` just prints 'ls' (tested on Solaris) (Nevermind, just saw the original answer)

Comment: @MustafaOzturk The `ls` is superfluous. `for f in abc*; ...` is all you need.

Comment: ls does not work well when there are too many files in the directory.

Answer (score 5):

This may do what you want:

```
find /dev \( ! -name /dev -prune \) -type f -print
```

Comment: Yes, this works. -maxdepth isn't implemented in find on some older Unixes.

Answer (score 4):

I got here with a bit more general problem - I wanted to find files in directories matching pattern but not in their subdirectories.

My solution (assuming we're looking for all `cpp` files living directly in `arch` directories):

`find . -path "*/arch/*/*" -prune -o -path "*/arch/*.cpp" -print`

I couldn't use maxdepth since it limited search in the first place, and didn't know names of subdirectories that I wanted to exclude.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative to find called rawhide (rh) and it's much easier to use. Instead of:

```
find /dev -maxdepth 1 -name 'abc-*'
```

You can do:

```
rh -r /dev '"abc-*"'
```

The -r is the same as "-m1 -M1" which is the same as find's "-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1", just a lot shorter.

Rawhide (rh) is available from https://raf.org/rawhide or https://github.com/raforg/rawhide. It works at least on Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Solaris, macOS, and Cygwin.

Disclaimer: I am the current author of rawhide

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to search the current directory, make sure that you use `./` as the directory, and not just `.`

If I just do '.' it gives me all the files in the directory below the one I'm working in:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'abc-*'
```

Instead you will want something like (this specific example finds all files in the current directory above a specific size):

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.root" -type 'f' -size +100k -ls
564751   71 -rw-r--r--   1 snyder   bfactory   115739 May 21 12:39 ./R24eTightPiPi771052-55.root
565197  105 -rw-r--r--   1 snyder   bfactory   150719 May 21 14:27 ./R24eTightPiPi771106-2.root
565023   94 -rw-r--r--   1 snyder   bfactory   134180 May 21 12:59 ./R24eTightPiPi77999-109.root
719678   82 -rw-r--r--   1 snyder   bfactory   121149 May 21 12:42 ./R24eTightPiPi771098-10.root
564029  140 -rw-r--r--   1 snyder   bfactory   170181 May 21 14:14 ./combo77v.root
```