# How do I include a list of sub-directories when using `find`?

Tags: file, directory, find

Although I could not find an example of what I want to achieve, I thought this would be easy given examples that would appear to have similar logic, eg [How do I exclude a directory when using `find`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-do-i-exclude-a-directory-when-using-find), [How to only find files in a given directory, and ignore subdirectories using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715485/how-to-only-find-files-in-a-given-directory-and-ignore-subdirectories-using-bas), [How to combine 2 -name conditions in find?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50612/how-to-combine-2-name-conditions-in-find#:%7E:text=expression%20%2Do%20expression%3A%20Alternation%20of,the%20first%20expression%20is%20true.).  Yet again, I have been proven wrong :(

I have a number of directories under /data/csvfiles

```
cd /data/csvFiles/
ls -l
drwxr-x---. dir1
drwxr-x---. dir2
drwxr-x---. dir3
drwxr-x---. dir4
drwxr-x---. dir5
drwxr-x---. dir6
drwxr-x---. dir7
```

I would like to find all *.gz files within directories dir2, dir3, dir5, dir7

As you may guess, the directories have different names to that illustrated.
*(Also, my find is much more complex to that being discussed.  The bash script asks for start and end times, and pipes to a zgrep, being passed to a list of server names for ssh.).  I have included a simple pipe to 'sort' to represent this.*

Starting with the basics

```
find /data/csvFiles/ -type f -name "*.gz" | sort
```

Reading the linked discussion, my first attempt is

```
find /data/csvFiles/ -type d \( -path ./dir2 -o -path ./dir3 -o -path ./dir4 \) -type f -name "*.gz" | sort
```

This returns nothing, which I believe is due to the use of ./
I then cautiously backtrack to a single directory before attempting a list.  hoping the use of `*dir*` will make it 'relative' to /data/csvFiles.

`find /data/csvFiles/ -path '*dir2*' -type f -name "*.gz" | sort`

This works, but notice that I have switched from **-type d** to **-path** (reading the answers to different questions).

I then try and combine the working  (using -path) example with the format provided in an answer which uses a list

```
find /data/csvFiles/ -type d \( -path '*dir2*' \) -type f -name "*.gz" | sort
```

Again, nothing is returned, although I know files name *.gz exist in /data/csvFiles/dir2.

I have tried many combinations and would be grateful if someone can explain how to add a list of subdirectories, which I would guess is something like

```
find /data/csvFiles/ -type d \( -path '*dir2*' -o -path '*dir2*' -o -path '*dir3*' -o -path '*dir5*' -o '-path *dir7*' \) -type f -name "*.gz" | sort
```

Comment: Not sure if my question is considered to be ridiculous, or it has not intrigued the stackoverflow collective enough to respond (????)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am unsure why type -d does not appear to work with -path, I am guessing the community believes my question does not warrant a response, as the answer is fairly simple.
Stepping away from the linked discussions, it occurred to me that I only need the -path 'test'.

```
find /data/csvFiles/ \( -path '*dir2*' -o -path '*dir2*' -o -path '*dir3*' -o -path '*dir5*' -o '-path *dir7*' \) -type f -name "*.gz" | sort
```

I believe the above works...
*(although I actually have /data/csvFiles/tmp/dir2 which messes things up.  Ideally, I only want to test the first directory level after start point, but -depth appears to clash.  However, that is a different question.  NB I know about -prune, but I am wondering if it is possible to test by depth).*

**EDIT**
I am wrong again, -maxdepth does work.  I thought it would be relative to the start position, which it is, but it appears the start position is 1, and the proceeding level makes 1+1.

```
find /data/csvFiles/ -maxdepth 2 \( -path '*dir2*' -o -path '*dir2*' -o -path '*dir3*' -o -path '*dir5*' -o '-path *dir7*' \) -type f -name "*.gz" | sort
```

The above is the solution I was looking for.