# Exclude a sub-directory using find

Tags: bash, unix

I have directory structure like this

```
data
|___
   |
   abc
    |____incoming
   def
    |____incoming
    |____processed
   123
    |___incoming
   456
    |___incoming
    |___processed
```

There is an incoming sub-folder in all of the folders inside Data directory. I want to get all files from all the folders and sub-folders except the def/incoming and 456/incoming dirs.
I tried out with following command

```
 find /home/feeds/data -type d \( -name 'def/incoming' -o -name '456/incoming' -o -name arkona \) -prune -o -name '*.*' -print
```

but it is not working as expected.

Ravi

Comment: This is not good advice, but it will get you out of a lot of situations quick and dirty: pipe that to `grep -v something` to exclude whatever it is you don't want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command)

Answer (score 255, accepted):

This works:

```
find /home/feeds/data -type f -not -path "*def/incoming*" -not -path "*456/incoming*"
```

**Explanation:**

- `find /home/feeds/data`: start finding recursively from specified path
- `-type f`: find files only
- `-not -path "*def/incoming*"`: don't include anything with `def/incoming` as part of its path
- `-not -path "*456/incoming*"`: don't include anything with `456/incoming` as part of its path

Comment: getting an error "find: bad option -not
find: path-list predicate-list"

Comment: @Ravi are you using bash shell? I just tested this on my terminal and it works for me. Try copy and pasting the solution instead if you made modifications to your script.

Comment: Its working, but, its listing the dirs not files in those dirs.

Comment: @Ravi oh, sorry - I confused what you were looking for. Change `type d` to `-type f` and it will find files instead of directories (See updated answer)

Comment: `-path` matches the whole string, so if you're doing `find .`, then your `-path` strings need to be `./path/to/directory/*`

Comment: FYI `-not -path` definitely will work in this example but `find` is still iterating into the directory structure and using cpu cycles to iterate over all those directories/files. to prevent `find` from iterating over those directories/files (maybe there are millions of files there) then you need to use `-prune` (the `-prune` option is difficult to use however).

Answer (score 14):

Just for the sake of documentation: You might have to dig deeper as there are many search'n'skip constellations (like I had to). It might turn out that `prune` is your friend while `-not -path` won't do what you expect.

So this is a valuable example of 15 find examples that exclude directories:

http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/07/find-command-15-examples-to-exclude.html

To link to the initial question, excluding finally worked for me like this:

```
find . -regex-type posix-extended -regex ".*def/incoming.*|.*456/incoming.*" -prune -o -print
```

Then, if you wish to find one file and still exclude pathes, just add `| grep myFile.txt`.

It may depend also on your find version. I see:

```
$ find -version
GNU find version 4.2.27
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX
```

Comment: `-regex-type` does not exist on version 4.8.0, it is `-regextype`

Answer (score 5):

`-name` only matches the filename, not the whole path. You want to use `-path` instead, for the parts in which you are pruning the directories like `def/incoming`.

Answer (score 2):

```
find $(INP_PATH} -type f -ls |grep -v "${INP_PATH}/.*/"
```

Comment: Some explanations might make this into a much better answer.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Comment: Note: This trick does not work if one uses `find ... -print0` in conjunction with a later `xargs -0`

Answer (score 2):

By following answer for [How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4210072/2402577):

```
find . \( -name ".git" -o -name "node_modules" \) -prune -o -print
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to exclude all the `.git` directories and passed it to `-exec` for greping something in the

```
find . -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -exec grep "pattern" [] \;
```

- `-not -path '*/\.*'` will exclude all the hidden directories
- `-type f` will only list type file and then you can pass that to `-exec` or whatever you want todo