# find how to exclude path

Tags: bash, find

I want to find all files in /usr/ but not in /usr/share

from this post [Exclude a sub-directory using find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460482/exclude-a-sub-directory-using-find)
I tried:

```
find /usr -type f -not -path /usr/share -print
```

-> print files from /usr/share

from this post [How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command)
I tried:

```
find /usr -path /usr/share -prune -print
```

->outputs nothing  altough there are files in /usr/bin

I also tried:

```
find /usr -path ! /usr/share -type f -print
```

-> outputs an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop `-print` and negate `-path ... -prune`:

```
find /usr ! \( -path '/usr/share' -prune \) -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, a boolean `and` is used to join operators and primaries.  So `find /usr -path /usr/share -prune -print` is equvialent to `find /usr -path /usr/share -prune -a -print`.  But you want to print things that are not pruned.  So use:

```
find /usr -path /usr/share -prune -o -print
```

If you want to limit the search to regular files:

```
find /usr -path /usr/share -prune -o -type f -print
```

Comment: for an explanation of the "prune or print" construct, run `man find` and type `/^ *Pruning` to search for the section that describes how it works. It was too long to paste in here, but the search will take you right to it.