# How to use Jenkins shell command to copy files but excluding some directories

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, command, continuous-integration

In a Jenkins job, I have a build step executing shell commands like this:

```
rm -rf /var/www/www.example.com/* 
find . \( -not -path '*/.svn/*' \) -exec cp -rv {} /var/www/www.example.com \;
```

However every time files in those folders such as .../classes/.svn/props are still copied.

I checked the find command manual, and the command seems correctly formed. So why is it not working? Also what is the purpose of putting a semicolon at the end? I copied this from somewhere :-)

I spent a few hours on this and still cannot get it work, so painful. Maybe using rsync is a better choice.

Comment: Have to tried the answer for this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring .svn directories in your find command, but after that you do a recursive copy of directories, so if a directory contains a .svn directory you will still copy it. (and also your command does perform a lot of duplicate copies)

There are lots of options for copying directories excluding svn files - in your case I'd start with removing the -r.

If the above does not work google 'copy files without svn directories' for lots of different options.

Comment: Well even I removed the -r, the .svn folders are still copied, maybe because they are hidden folders. -prune is not working either. I give this up instead use rsync which is a lot easier. Trying different combinations of find options is really time wasting and depressing, I was unwise to pick this solution in my case. But thanks to all who have replied!