# How exclude files / folders for remove

Tags: shell, command-line

How can I remove all in folder and exclude specific folders and files?

(As example with tar: `tar --exclude="folder"`).

Edit: I can delete files and folders.

Comment: What do you mean by `remove`?  Delete?  What is that you want to accomplish?

Comment: Yes - delete files. I use command rm. Sorry bad formulate question.

Comment: Thanks, [exclude directory from find . command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command) is answer.

Comment: One of the best and short command I mostly use is this below. Exclude file or folder with !(FileName, DirectoryName or Wildcard with prefix or suffix) then add -rf to recursively delete directory and files.

Example:  rm !(*.txt) -rf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

NOTE: Be careful running the following commands.

```
find . -type 'f' | grep -v "NameToExclude" | xargs rm 
find . -type 'd' | grep -v "NameToExclude" | xargs rmdir
```

Comment: find .  -maxdepth 1  ! -name root  ! -name . | xargs rm -r

Comment: How about using the ls command: rm -fr $(ls -1 --ignore=nameToExclude .)

Comment: Slight modification, if you use `egrep` you can specify multiple names: `find . -maxdepth 1 | egrep -v "folder1|folder2" | xargs rm`