# delete files from linux directory exluding some directories

Tags: linux, unix, rm

I have the directory structure like

/Folder1/Folder1a/Folder1b
/Folder1/Folder2a/Folder2b
/Folder1/Folder2a/Folder2c
/Folder1/Folder3a
/Folder1/Folder4a

I want to recursively delete the files from /Folder1/ but want to exclude the location /Folder1/Folder2a/Folder2c.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184956/how-exclude-files-folders-for-remove

Comment: It gives a basic idea but i want to delete the files and exclude the directory completely

I had tested this
find /Folder1/ -type 'd' | grep -v "/Folder1/Folder2a/Folder2c" | xargs ls -l {} \; &

Comment: `find . -type 'f' | grep -v "Folder1/Folder2a/Folder2b" | xargs rm` doesn't do what you're looking for?

Comment: I think i wrote the question wrong
i need to exclude a couple of folders from the deletions and i need to keep the data in all directories for 45 days, i modified it a little and came up with this
nohup find /Folder1/ -type 'd' -mtime +45 | grep -v "NameToExclude" | xargs ls -l {} \; &