# excluding a directory from find and sed rename

Tags: linux, bash, replace, sed, find

I'm using this command to go through all files, directories and subdirectories to change any mentions of `oldurl.com` to `newurl.org`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's|oldurl.com|newurl.org|g' {} +
```

It works fine, however, I need to exclude three sub-directories from ANY CHANGES: `/cache`, `/archive` and `/etc` as changing the urls with the above command in these paths breaks other scripts.

Haven't had much luck finding an answer... Is it even possible?

Many thanks for any suggestions/help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [exclude directory from find . command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use finds `-not` Option:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -not \( -path './etc/*' -o -path './cache/*' -o -path './archive/*'  \) -exec sed -i 's|oldurl.com|newurl.org|g' {} \;
```