# Why is find finding .git directories?

Tags: bash, find

I have the following `find` command and I'm surprised to see `.git` directories being found. Why?

```
$ find . ! -name '*git*' | grep git 
./.git/hooks
./.git/hooks/commit-msg
./.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
./.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
./.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
./.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
./.git/hooks/post-update.sample
```

Comment: The predicates apply to the last component of the pathname only.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Bash and would be a better fit at [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because find searches for files and none of the found files have the search pattern in their name (see the man page). You need to remove the offending directory via the `-prune` switch:

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -o -not -name '*git*' -print |grep git
```

See [Exclude directory from find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command)

[edit] An alternative without `-prune` (and much more natural imho):

```
find . -not -path "*git*" -not -name '*git*' |grep git
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just seeing expected behaviour of `find`.  The `-name` test is only applied to the filename itself, not the whole path.  If you want to search everything but the `.git` directory, you can use [`bash(1)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)'s [`extglob`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) option:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ find !(.git)
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really find those git-files. Instead it finds files under ./.git/ that match the pattern `! -name '*git*'` which includes all files that don't include `git` in their filename (not path name).
Finds `-name` is about the files, not the path.

Try `-iwholename` instead of `-name`:
`find . ! -iwholename '*git*'`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed:

```
find . ! -path '*git*'
```