# Exclude sub directories from find: why is -not -path not working?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, find

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/simian-2.3.35/bin/simian-2.3.35.jar files $(find ~/App/Classes/ -type f -name "*.m"  -not -path  "Lib/excludethisdir/*")
```

I'm trying to run simian and pass a file argument into it, but excluding a directory just isn't working. The Lib directory is contained in Classes

Can anyone point out why it's not working (The command runs, but it doesn't exclude)

Comment: possible duplicate of [exclude directory from find . command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command)

Comment: Also not sure exactly what `simian` is, but this will fail on files that contain whitespace, and can run past `ARG_MAX` if `find` returns a lot of files.

Comment: Hi BroSlow, simian is a copy paste detector written in Java. The files don't have whitespace. It doesn't seem to be hitting `ARG_MAX` as the command runs - 678 files.

Answer (score 15):

You nested find command should be:

```
find ~/App/Classes/ -type f -name "*.m"  -not -path "./Lib/excludethisdir/*"
```

i.e. add `./` before your excluded path.

Or even better:

```
find ~/App/Classes/ -path "./Lib/excludethisdir/*" -prune -o -type f -name "*.m" -print
```

Comment: Worth noting that `-prune` is faster, i.e. something like `find ~/App/Classes/ -path "./Lib/excludethisdir" -prune -o -type f -name "*.m" -print` is faster than checking it each time.

Comment: Thanks @BroSlow: I added it to my answer.

Comment: Hi anubhava, this still doesn't work for me. Could it have something to do with where I am running the command from? I am in the "App" directory when I run this command, and "Lib" is a subdirectory of "Classes"

Comment: Yes you need to give full path to exclude.. So give `"./classes/Lib/excludethisdir/*`