# How to Blacklist Subdirectories for Recursive Mocha Tests?

Tags: mocha.js

When using the `--recursive` flag with `mocha`, what is the best method to ignore subdirectories within `test/`?

As an example, I have a `test/x`, `test/y`, `test/z` directory containing tests, more of which can be added and removed all the time (so maintaining a whitelist would be tedious).
I also have `test/utilities` and `test/integration` which contain code I don't want executed by mocha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a slightly modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595367) answer to find the script directories.

Since you're using the `--recursive` flag, I only found directories at depth 1.

```
mocha --recusive $(find test -not \( -path test/utilities -prune \) -not \( -path test/integration -prune \) -type d -depth 1)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! NB: if embedding that command into package.json be sure to double escape the escapes.

Comment: `-d` is now deprecated, should be `-depth` instead:

```mocha --recusive $(find test -not \( -path test/utilities -prune \) -not \( -path test/integration -prune \) -type d -depth 1)```