# Quickly find and print all files in a folder, recursively, excluding ones from `node_modules` and `.git`

Tags: shell, find

Consider the following folder structure starting in some root folder

```
/root/
/root/.git
/root/node_modules
/root/A/
/root/A/stuff1/
/root/A/stuff2/
/root/A/node_modules/
/root/B/
/root/A/stuff1/
/root/A/stuff2/
/root/B/node_modules/
...
```

Now I am in `/root` and I'd like to find all my own files inside it.
I have a small number of my own files and the **huge number of files inside `node_modules` and `.git`**.

Because of that, traversing `node_modules` and filtering it out is unacceptable, as it takes too much time. I want the command to *never enter the `node_modules` or `.git` folder*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For excluding files only directly from the folder of the search:

```
find . -not \( -path './.git' -prune \) -not \( -path './node_modules' -prune \) -type f
```

If you want to exclude certain paths that are *in subfolders*, you can do that too using `*` wildcard.

Say you have `node_modules` too inside `stuff1` and `stuff2`, and additionally `dist` and `lib` folders:

```
find . -not \( -path './.git' -prune \) -not \( -path './node_modules' -prune \) -not \( -path './*/node_modules' -prune \) -not \( -path './*/dist' -prune \)  -not \( -path './*/lib' -prune \) -type f
```

Tested on Windows using git bash 1.9.5

It seems however it does not work properly on Windows when a filter like `-name '*.js'` is passed. The workaround could be to not use `-name` and pipe to `grep` instead.

Kudos to [@Daniel C. Sobral](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595367/245966)