# 'Sed' not working on result of 'find' with multiple parameters

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find

I'm trying to do a find and replace function, finding files which match a criteria then find/replace text within them.

Find statement (works find and returns list of files):

`find / -type f -name "*.properties" -o -name "*.xml" -not \( -path '/tmp/*' -o -path '/var/tmp/*'  \)`

Sed find/replace:

```
sed -i 's/find/replace/g' {} \;
```

Putting together:

```
find / -type f -name "*.properties" -o -name "*.xml" -not \( -path '/tmp/*' -o -path '/var/tmp/*'  \) -exec sed -i 's/10\.32\.19\.156/10.32.19.165/g' {} \;
```

However this does not seem to work. Removing some 'find' parameters causes it to work, for example this works:

```
find / -type f -name "*.properties" -exec sed -i 's/10\.32\.19\.156/10.32.19.165/g' {} \;
```

How can I get sed to work with the extended 'find' parameters?
Currently these two 'find' statements return exactly the same result in a test folder with only 2 files:

```
find /var/tmp/ipreplace/ -type f -name "*.properties"

find /var/tmp/ipreplace/ -type f -name "*.properties" -o -name "*.xml" -not \( -path '/tmp/*' -o -path '/var/tmp/*'  \)
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use -not in your find query? find /var/tmp/ipreplace will restrict find to search in that directory only and other parameters are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the use of `-path` parameter in your `find` command is wrong.
Try the following:

```
find / -not \( -path '/tmp' -prune \) -not \( -path '/var/tmp' -prune \) -type f -name "*.properties" -o -name "*.xml" -exec sed -i 's/10\.32\.19\.156/10.32.19.165/g' {} \;
```

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command) for reference