# How can I exclude a directory but not its content using the find command?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I use the following command in a scheduled Cron task to delete all files older than 30 days in a folder called `Downloads`:

```
find /home/orschiro/Downloads -path ./Archiveror -prune -path ./Fairphone -prune -o -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \; && notify-send "Searching for old files..."
```

Thereby, I want to exclude:

- the folder `Archiveror` with all its content which it does
- and the folder `Fairphone` but keep its content checked if older than 30 days

How do can I tell the `find` command to not delete the folder `Fairphone` but its content if older than 30 days?

Comment: this didnt helped you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command

Comment: I found this thread but couldn't find the information how to keep the contents of an excluded directory from not being excluded.