# How to exclude multiple subdirectories when using "find" command?

Tags: linux, path, find, subdirectory

I was looking for "*.py" files, and exclude both "build" and "bin" directories. I used this command:

```
find * -path "build" -prune -path "bin" -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.py" \) -print > findpyfiles.txt
```

The "findpyfiles.txt" still contains results started with "bin/".
How to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude directory from find . command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

Although the question has an answer elsewhere, it may be worth knowing why your command didn't work right: You omitted an *operator* between `-path "build" -prune` and `-path "bin" -prune`, and *`-and` is assumed where the operator is omitted*, thus the `-path "bin"` is not evaluated when `-path "build"` returns *false*. Explicitly specifying the *OR* operator fixes it, either

```
find * -path build -prune -o -path bin -prune -o -type f -name "*.py" -print >findpyfiles.txt
```

or

```
find * \( -path build -o -path bin \) -prune -o -type f -name "*.py" -print >findpyfiles.txt
```