# Python-ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.migrations.migration'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, wagtail

I got this error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.migrations.migration'** after i tried these below steps

1. `python3 manage.py migrate --fake resources zero` (resources is my
   app name)
2. `find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete`
3. `find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete`
4. `python3 manage.py showmigrations`

**Note**: used PostgreSQL

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43548690/5644965) out

Answer (score 6):

By running those commands you might have accidentally deleted the migrations module. Try reinstalling Django via pip.
`pip uninstall django`
`pip install django`

Take note of the version of Django you are using. In case you aren't using the latest version for your python environment install using the following command
`pip install django==<version goes here>`

Edit:-

Drop the existing database schema. Delete the migrations folder and recreate an empty one in its place.

Comment: thanks,it solves but i got reference error after reinstalling django **django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration home.0012_auto_20170615_1318 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('wagtailimages', '0019_delete_filter')**

Comment: Did you drop the database? See the edit on my answer above. Please accept the anwer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to [force reinstall Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382997/888367) in order to restore the base migrations folder.

Answer (score 0):

#### Just install

```
pip3 install django-reset-migrations
```