# How to find the files recursively having a text pattern excluding some directories and files

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How to find the files recursively having a text pattern excluding some directories and files?

```
Example:- 
$ ls
bower.json      bower_components    configure       results         unit-tests
```

so I need to find "searchText" recursively in all directories excluding bower.json and results

Comment: Use a method from https://stackoverflow.com/q/4210042/798223 then use the -exec flag to grep on those files.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact command? This is not working .  find  -name "*.js"  -not -path results

Comment: `find -type f -not -path './bower.json' -not -path './results/*' -exec grep 'searchString' -- '{}' +`, but @RomanPerekhrest's answer is better.

Comment: Also I've flagged this question, as originally I marked it as a duplicate of the wrong thing, hopefully that should get fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks GKFX!. I even find grep solution much better and clean approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short ***grep*** solution:

```
grep -r --exclude="bower.json" --exclude-dir="results" "searchText"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just one minor thing. You need to put  dot(.) in last. grep -r --exclude="bower.json" --exclude-dir="results" "reset-device" .

Comment: @nagendra547, welcome, dot `.` is intended by default