# Send message to Slack when new files are available in folder

Tags: bash, curl, find, slack-api

Im trying to send a slack message if there is a file available thats newer than a day.

Full command

```
find . -mtime -1 -exec curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/FooBar {} \;
```

the command doest work but throws an error.

output:

`okcurl: (6) Could not resolve host:
okcurl: (6) Could not resolve host:
okcurl: (6) Could not resolve host:`

Comment: You need a space after the closing single quote.  Voting to close as typo.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @tripleee ! sadly it doesn't work

Comment: I edited my question to clarify some things

Comment: You *still* need a space after the quote. If you're actually doing that, edit your question to reflect it. Also, you're passing the filenames found by the `find` command to `curl`, which will try to interpret them as hostnames. It's likely that is the source of your error because it is unlikely that those filenames are valid hostnames.

Comment: I'm not passing any variables found by find to the Curl command I also added the space in my command

Comment: You probably have DOS line endings in the script file. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Comment: Yes, you do. `find` will replace `{}` by the found files. I assume that the current directory `.` is the first file found.

Comment: This is not "a simple typographical error" as alleged by some commentators here, but a problem with the correct syntax of the bash command. See my answer for the solution. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by @larsks the filenames inserted via `{}` into the `curl` are apparently interpreted as host names and therefore generating that error.

It works if you put the `{}` into the text property of the message, which will then include the found filename in the message to the Slack webhook. I guess it would also make sense to not only send a message, but also include the name of that file in that message.

```
find . -mtime -1 -exec curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World! {}"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/FooBar \;
```

Or if you don't want to show the found filenames on Slack you can just omit the `{}` altogether:

```
find . -mtime -1 -exec curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/FooBar \;
```

Finally, I would assume you do not want to send a message for the "." directory, so you need to exclude it: (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15736463/4379151))

```
find . -mtime -1 -not -path "." -exec curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/Foobar \;
```

Comment: thank you! that worked for me!