# Delete all directories excluding a specific one

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

On a linux host, given an absolute path, I want to delete all except a certain directory. 
To simplify things below is the directory structure and I want to delete all directories except test2

```
[root@hostname test]# pwd
/opt/data/test
root@hostname test]# ls -ltr
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Dec  5 09:33 test1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  5 09:44 test2
[root@hostname test]#
```

I looked into [How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command) and tried the prune switch like this

```
[root@hostname test]# find /opt/data/test -type d -path test2 -prune 
-o ! -name "test2" -print
/opt/data/test
/opt/data/test/test1
/opt/data/test/test1/ls.txt
/opt/data/test/test1/test13
/opt/data/test/test1/test13/temp.py
/opt/data/test/test1/test13/try.pl
/opt/data/test/test1/test11
/opt/data/test/test1/test11/ls.txt
/opt/data/test/test1/test11/temp.py
/opt/data/test/test1/test11/try.pl
/opt/data/test/test1/test12
/opt/data/test/test1/test12/ls.txt
/opt/data/test/test1/test12/temp.py
/opt/data/test/test1/test12/try.pl
/opt/data/test/test1/temp.py
/opt/data/test/test1/try.pl
/opt/data/test/test2/ls.txt
/opt/data/test/test2/temp.py
/opt/data/test/test2/try.pl
[root@hostname test]
```

now it lists all the folder including /opt/data/test and if I add the xargs rm -rf to this, it will delete the parent folder as well. I don't think I understood the concept -path and -name correctly, please help

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple negation with `-not` may be easier than pruning:

```
$ find /opt/data/test -type d -not -name test2
```

**EDIT:**

There's no reason to recurse in to the subdirectories, since you're going to delete the top directories anyway, so you could add `-maxdepth` and avoid finding the directories inside `test2`:

```
$ find /opt/data/test -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name test2
```

Comment: One problem with both the prune solution and this is that it also includes the folders within test2. As a result when I add pipe this with xargs rm -rf the contents within test2 are lost. How do I avoid this?      [root@hostname test]# ls
test1  test2  test3  test4
[root@hostname test]# cd
[root@hostname-0 ~]# find /opt/data/test -type d -not -name test2
/opt/data/test
/opt/data/test/test1
/opt/data/test/test1/test13
/opt/data/test/test1/test11
/opt/data/test/test1/test12
/opt/data/test/test2/test23
/opt/data/test/test2/test22
/opt/data/test/test2/test24
/opt/data/test/test2/test21

Comment: @Mukta You can use `-maxdepth`, see my edited answer.

Comment: -maxdepth helped

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the required behavior by adding -mindepth 1 to the find command to exclude the parent directory.