# Using array for `ls --ignore`

Tags: arrays, bash, ubuntu, ls

I'm working on a bash script for my server backup.
Based on my web root(/home), I wanna filter my web directories excludes something generals.
I found **--ignore** option for it. Here's my code for returng what I want.

```
DIR_LIST=`ls -al $WWW_ROOT --ignore={.,..,ubuntu,test} | grep "^d" | awk '{ print $9 }'`
echo $DIR_LIST;
```

But when I tried with array, it's not worked as well.

```
EXCLUDED=(. .. test ubuntu)
STR=$(IFS=,; echo "${EXCLUDED[*]}")
DIR_LIST=`ls -al $WWW_ROOT --ignore={$STR} | grep "^d" | awk '{ print $9 }'`
echo $DIR_LIST;
```

**echo $STR** works well but **echo $DIR_LIST** is not.
I think brace is not worked properly.

How can I do this as I expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it without using `ls` and to make matters worst you're using the `-al` flag.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob

files=(/path/to/www/directory/!(ubuntu|test)/)

declare -p files
```

That will show you the files in the array assignment.

If you want to loop through the files and remove the pathname from the file name without using any external commands from the shell.

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do echo "${f##*/}"; done
```

Which has the same result when using `basename`

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do var=$(basename "$f"); echo "$var"; done
```

Or just do it in the array

```
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]##*/}"
```

The `"${files##*/}"` is a form of P.E. parameter expansion.

There is an online bash manual where you can look up P.E. see [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Or the man page. see  `PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*parameter\ expansion' man bash`

Look up `nullglob` and `extglob` see [shell globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)

The array named `files` now has the data/files that you're interested in.

By default the dotfiles is not listed so you don't have to worry about it, unless `dotglob` is enabled which is off by default.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there a way to remove /path/to/www/directory/ from result? I need only base directory name for my job.

Comment: You mean remove the pathname from the filename?  You ca use a parameter expansion `"${files##*/}"`,  `for f in "${files[@]}"; do echo "${f##*/}"; done`

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is mostly right, but it has a few issues. Firstly the `ls` command uses the shell globbing style to expand your `--ignore` pattern. It works fine when you specified it explicitly.

But when you define it in a variable to expand the glob, the shell doesn't like it. Because when the shell expands the command line, it does the glob expansion first before expanding the variable. Since you have the glob within the variable, by the time it expands the variable, it has crossed a point where it can expand the glob, so your `--ignore` pattern is never really formed with the way you expect it to be.

Also, the way you are populating the array, its not recommended to take that approach, because it is fragile ( [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls(1)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) ), when it comes to dealing with names involving spaces/newline or any other shell metacharacters.

See [How to exclude a directory in `find .` command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4210042/5291015) to exclude directories when searching over a file system.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Really helped for me.

Answer (score -1):

if "ubuntu" and "test" is file, it should work. if they are directories, you need add dot "." , like ".test" or ".ubuntu" in EXCLUDED