# How to exclude CWD in a `find` command

Tags: bash

How can I exclude the current working directory (CWD) with find?

Consider my current working directory to contain the following directories (`ls .`):

```
a b c d e f g
```

Find command: `find . -maxDepth 1 -type d` will return:

```
.
./a
./b
./c
./d
./e
./f
./g
```

I tried the answer from here ([How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command)): `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -path . -prune -false`

While I can use `ls` I'd be curious how I could achieve the same with `find`.

So the expected output from a `find` command should be similar to the `ls .` output:

```
./a
./b
./c
./d
./e
./f
./g
```

Comment: Could you please try following, `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name '.' \) -print` if this helps you? BTW your `maxdepth` has `D` in it which should be `d` in `find` command.

Comment: there is an alternative to `find` called `fd` (https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) — Using this command yields the expected result immediately `fd --type directory --max-depth 1`

Comment: I'd rather not rely on external tools like `fd` because it can really be done with `find`.

Comment: @thanasisp eagle eye you are, I think it does.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-mindepth 1` option to avoid matching `.` (current) directory:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

To be able to match only single character directories:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '?'
```

Comment: @stephanmg You can even leave `.` out: `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`

Comment: @TedLyngmo: That is only allowed in `gnu find`. On BSD find it will give error

Comment: @anubhava Ah... I see. I've been using gnu find for too long I guess.

Comment: Oh then I presume I am on an GNU sed, because BSD sed give me in fact an error. (Verified)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, assuming you are setting `maxdepth` to `1` because you need to get only current directory's all directories.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name '.' \) -print
```

Comment: Perfectly, works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think also this should work: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -\! -name "." -prune`