# Exclude some files from variable in find command

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sed, find

I want to exclude some files in find command and it is not working very good! Here is what I did:

```
arg=$1
exclude="/etc/alternatives/awk 
    /usr/sbin/poweroff 
    /usr/bin/ls"

find $arg -type f,l,c,b -path /etc/alternatives/awk -prune -o -print
```

In this example I used only one file `/etc/alternatives/awk` and I don't know how to tell the script to act in my variable `exclude`.

## Update:

Should I only use this structure?

```
find $arg -type f,l,c,b -path /usr/bin/pwd -prune -o -path /etc/alternatives/awk -prune -o -path /usr/sbin/poweroff -prune -o -path /usr/bin/ls -prune -o -print
```

Comment: Could [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command) had multiple alternatives with pros/cons.
One of (the slowest):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
arg=$1
exclude='^/etc/alternatives/awk$|^/usr/sbin/poweroff$|^/usr/bin/ls$'

find $arg -type f,l,c,b | grep -Ev "${exclude}"
```

or you could try to do it natively with `find` without `grep`-ing:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
arg=$1
exclude='^(/etc/alternatives/awk|/usr/sbin/poweroff|/usr/bin/ls)$'

find $arg -type f,l,c,b -regextype posix-extended -not -regex "${exclude}" -print
```

Comment: Better to use this pattern: `exclude='^/etc/alternatives/awk$|^/usr/sbin/powerof$|^/usr/bin/ls$'`

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E` but that grep command will interpret regexp metachars so YMMV if any of the paths contain `.` or `*` or `?` or `[` or `(` or similar - you should really be using `grep -F -f '<list the paths in a file or here doc or here string or similar>'`. @M.J `^ab$|^cd$` = `^(ab|cd)$`

Comment: Thank you. could you rewrite the script in better way you mentioned? Maybe even as a seperate answer

Comment: @Vgersh99 Yes, that's it! +1