# Exclude specific path from find's output

Tags: shell, find

I searched inside my filesystem for files with a specific extension using find

```
find / -type f -name "*.click" 2>/dev/null
```

In my result I get a lot of files in a specific path which are not interesting for me like

```
/home/x/Dokumente/click/etc/samplepackage/test.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/apps/csclient/test.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/test-device.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/ip6ndadvertiser.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/script-parabolawave.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/fake-iprouter.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/fromhost-tunnel.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/simple-dsdv-userlevel.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/sampler.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/script-trianglewave.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/script-squarewave.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/fastudpsrc.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/schedorder1.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/test-ping-userlevel.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/test-tcp.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/delay.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/icmp6error.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/webgen.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/test2.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/grid.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/thomer-nat.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/gnat02.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/test-clicky.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/ip64-nat3.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/mazu-nat.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/ip6print.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/gnat01.click
/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/ip601.click
```

In [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command) I found an answer and tried like this below

```
find / -type f -name "*.click" -not -path "./home/ipg7/Dokumente/click/conf"  2>/dev/null
```

But it doesn't work I still get the output as before.

So how can I exclude a specific path and also write all the permission denied to /dev/null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added `-not -path "./home/ipg7/Dokumente/click/conf"` which does not match anything in your output due to

1. starting with a dot,
2. missing the pattern that matches the file part

Try `-not -path "/home/ipg7/Dokumente/click/conf/*"` instead

Comment: Ty, I understand now I compare it against the whole path right?

Comment: You compare against exactly what the output is, e.g. `/home/x/Dokumente/click/conf/ip6print.click`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use globbing in path to ignore all matches from a given path and use `2>/dev/null` to ignore error:

```sh
find / -type f -name "*.click" -not -path "./home/ipg7/Dokumente/click/conf/*" 2>/dev/null
```