# Is there a version of the command line `find` that uses caching for better performance?

Tags: command-line, find

`find` is sometimes a bit slow for large directories. This can sometimes be resolved by [excluding files and directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command).

Is there a version of find that supports caching for better performance. Similar to [ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) but for the details about their files rather than their content.

Related:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78726/find-ls-caching
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1006135/can-you-cache-the-find-command (suggests locate)
- [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/313735/150615) to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/313733/how-do-i-use-the-locate-command-within-a-specified-directory) shows how you can run `updatedb` on a particular directory and then use `locate`.

Answer (score 1):

find already does use caching.

Edit: Actually I don't know what it does but the first time you run the command is slower than the rest. Perhaps it's just indicing.

Comment: Hmm, how come `locate` is faster than `find`?

Comment: I have no idea but if you run the same find command several times, the first run will be slower than the rest.

Comment: Hmm... yeah the inodes for the find will probably be kept cached to improve performance. I guess locate mind be creating *indexes* for some forms of searching.

Comment: I was just gonna say, perhaps find uses indicing and not caching.

Comment: I think the answer might be "find can't be made faster, only certain operations with indexes". I guess you might be able to sort of copy all the inode information for all the subdirectories into one big file to improve performance.

Comment: @Simaster "perhaps find uses indicing not caching" do you mean locate or find?

Comment: I meant find. But it doesn't really matter since I also said "perhaps". It means I know nothing :) sorry