# Locally installed OpenCV to virtual env in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, virtualenv, opencv3.0

I spent two whole days to install OpenCV, virtualenv, Tensorflow.
My last goal is to link locally installed OpenCV to my virtualenv.
I reallized that I do not have to install OpenCV to my virtualenv again, only need to link
OpenCV to my virtualenv.
I have to find "cv2.so" or "cv2.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so" file.
But I can't find any of above file in my Raspberry Pi 4.
Anybody can tell me where to find above files or how to link the locally installed OpenCV to virtualenv.
I really want to run a python program importing cv2 and tensorflow.

Comment: In the shell run `sudo find / -name cv2.so` and it will find this file if it is present on the machine. Likewise with the other file.

Comment: find: ‘/tmp/tmp.3YgQjldPvx’: Input/output error
find: File system loop detected; ‘/tmp/tmp.rIOenW5uji’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/’.
/etc/dhcpcd.conf
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied -> I come across this error message

Comment: In this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command you can learn how to exclude directories from the search using `find`. The error message indicates you should exclude the dir `/tmp` from the search. Also the `/run` directory.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks a lot.