# How to hash the (possibly recursive) contents of a directory

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, unix, hash

What I'm trying to do is know what particular subdirectories have changed after pulling from a git repository.  I was thinking I could compute the hash of all the subdirectories in the root directory, then pull git, then compute the hashes again. If the hashes don't match, then I know which directories have changed.

Is there a common way to compute the hash of a directory tree?  I feel like this is pretty much what git does internally to track its files.

I would prefer a C, or better yet, objective-c api to do this, but i'd settle for a unix command to do it.

thanks for any tips.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux: compute a single hash for a given folder & contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545387/linux-compute-a-single-hash-for-a-given-folder-contents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing a hash of a directory hierarchy is expensive, especially in a large git repository.

You should look at the API provided by git. There may be a way to ask git to tell you what it is changing.

You should look at OS X's file system events API. This can send your app a notification when something in a directory hierarchy changes.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html