# How can I create a hash of a directory in Linux in Shell or Python?

Tags: python, linux, shell, directory-structure, hash-function

What's the easiest way to get a hash-function of a directory in *Linux* (preferably using *shell scripting* or *Python*)?

What I'm trying to do is find duplicate subtrees within a large tree of directories.

`fdupes` and `meld` etc. tend to want the two trees to be largely isomorphic, ie. given

```
A
└─ B
```

and

```
A
└─ C
   └─ B
```

they won't alert me if B is the same in both trees because in the second tree its under C.

So I'm guessing I need to write my own script to recurse down both trees and find hashes of all subtrees and then compare them.

Comment: with same you mean the same inode or the same directory name?

Comment: You just want to find directories with same names ?

Comment: I mean "the same" as in all the files within them (including, recursively, all files in all subdirectories) are identical. This is for deduping purposes.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Linux: compute a single hash for a given folder & contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/545387/950485)

Comment: @rld I need to hash the contents of the files as well just their names.

Comment: Could you comment on the accepted answer to point out the version you ended up using, for future reference?

Comment: @rld. Basically I accepted it for the idea of doing a hash of the result of running "find" on each directory. I'm not using any of the suggestions exactly, but I'm constructing a solution (still tweaking it) based on that idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hash a directory's structure using filenames only

List all filepaths in the dir (recursively), `sort` them (in case `find` messes up), hash it all with `sha1sum` and print the hash:

```
find /my/dir -mindepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -z | sha1sum
```

You can put that in a script, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# hashtree-names.sh - hash a dir's structure by filenames
# (files with same names are considered identical)
# Usage: hashtree-names.sh <dirname>
DIR=$1
find $DIR -mindepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -z | sha1sum
```

And execute it on every dir under a large tree like so:

```
find /my/tree -mindepth 1 -type d -exec hashtree-names.sh {} \; | sort
```

Which will produce output similar to:

```
3cd8fea391f3055d9de3d6e05a422b6e97ce4204 *-
8cd93d83e9baeea479785fe0cc03c8b58aa293a3 *-
8cd93d83e9baeea479785fe0cc03c8b58aa293a3 *-
fe7dd981bb0d978608ba648eb3d38bb41f6cd956 *-
afc483808be60fbd48e716a7b916b5deaa9c78b5 *-
a518cfa27e7e9afbab2ba2209c80dbab0631736b *-
251f3cfc11eeccdfaf28142dadc5aa3aa4e2aec1 *-
251f3cfc11eeccdfaf28142dadc5aa3aa4e2aec1 *-
4a689e7c27733498c4ac5730f172c844cb6b21d1 *-
600a61b8c1a973aa6322ab4a7d57f7c07174e0ec *-
a401f27520252ae334625ca1b452396f0287f42d *-
e0b2d5f825f062d40f0f2490673888b5eb6c66fd *-
85a533625c5a38892d392f2ae9e7974e3eceaf6a *-
```

### Hash a directory's structure, complete with file contents

See [Vatine's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545413/950485) and [David Schmitt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545420/950485) answers to *[Linux: compute a single hash for a given folder & contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/545387/950485)*.

### EDIT 2017-01-27

- Code improvements: Added `-mindepth 1` to `find`